# global() function for list in python

Tags: python

Python: 3.8.1

I am unable to append data in class variables using global() function.

```
class test():
    __cv__ = []

        def testglobalmethod(self, data):
            globals()['__cv__']=[data]
            print(__cv__)


    rrr = test()
    rrr.testglobalmethod("1")
    rrr.testglobalmethod("2")
```

**Expected Results:-**
['1','2']

**Actual Results:-**
['1']
['2']

The append function produces below error:-

```
def testglobalmethod(self, data):
    globals()['__cv__'].append(data)
    print(__cv__)
```

Error: **`KeyError: '__cv__'`**

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @wim I have learned the global() function recently. I tried with string and worked perfectly fine. So, I am trying with the list to see how it works.

Comment: ``__cv__`` isn't global, it's a class attribute. Why do you expect to be able to access it via ``globals``? Is it intentional that all your code is part of the ``test`` class scope?

Comment: Don't invent your own dunder names; they are reserved for use by the language itself. Just use `cv`, or `_cv` if you want to emphasize that it is for use by methods of the `test` class alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a class attribute, not a global variable.

```
class Test():
    __cv__ = []

    def testglobalmethod(self, data):
        Test.__cv__.append(data)
        print(Test.__cv__)


rrr = Test()
rrr.testglobalmethod("1")
rrr.testglobalmethod("2")
```